# Android Server connect to C# Client

Tags: c#, android

I turned on my mobile's hotspot and connected my computer to the hotspot
and used this code to create server but InetAddress became "/0.0.0.0":

```
 ServerSocket ss = null;
        try {
            ss=  new ServerSocket(4444);

            //texto.append("\n"+ss.getInetAddress());
            Log.d("TcpServer", ss.getInetAddress()+"");
            log= ss.getInetAddress().toString();
            //ss.setSoTimeout(10000);
            //accept connections
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            Log.i("TcpServer", "Receiving");
            //texto.append("\n"+"Receiving");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            //BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            //receive a message
            Log.i("TcpServer", in.readLine());
            final String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            Log.i("TcpServer", "received: " + incomingMsg);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  //  texto.append("received: " + incomingMsg);

                }
            });

            s.close();
```

Comment: The client connects to the server, not the other way around. The server listens to clients.

Comment: I suggest you persue the solution to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074310/send-data-from-android-to-c-sharp#comment26453278_18074310). The solution to your problem is not making the Android client the server!

Comment: Thank you the answer was very good

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you just create a socket, the default is to listen on all network devices/all assigned IP addresses, which is reflected by listening on IP `0.0.0.0`.